# Replace first n rows with a new value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I tried this :
df['CC'].head(20)=2000 (Got Error)
df.head(20)

This is my data:

```
    Price   Age       KM FuelType  ...      CC  Doors  Weight  Horse Power
0   13500  23.0  46986.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1165.0        180.0
1   13750  23.0  72937.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1165.0        180.0
2   13950  24.0  41711.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1165.0        180.0
3   14950  26.0  48000.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1165.0        180.0
4   13750  30.0  38500.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1170.0        180.0
5   12950  32.0  61000.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1170.0        180.0
6   16900  27.0  94612.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1245.0        180.0
7   18600  30.0  75889.0   Diesel  ...  2000.0      3  1245.0        180.0
8   21500  27.0  19700.0   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
9   12950  23.0  71138.0   Diesel  ...  1900.0      3  1105.0        138.0
10  20950  25.0  31461.0   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
11  19950  22.0  43610.0   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
12  19600  25.0  32189.0   Petrol  ...  2000.0      3  1185.0        384.0
13  21500  31.0  23000.0   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
14  22500  32.0  34131.0   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
15  22000  28.0      NaN   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
16  22750  30.0  34000.0   Petrol  ...  1800.0      3  1185.0        384.0
17  17950  24.0  21716.0   Petrol  ...  2000.0      3  1105.0        220.0
18  16750  24.0  25563.0   Petrol  ...  1600.0      3  1065.0        220.0
19  16950  30.0  64359.0   Petrol  ...  1600.0      3  1105.0        220.0
```

[Image of the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJwfn.png)
Can anybody tell me how to replace the first n rows of a column with new values?

Comment: `df.loc[:20, 'CC'] = 2000` if you'd prefer to avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: @j1-lee thank you it worked

Comment: @j1-lee: don't do multiple slices like that, do a single slice like HenryEcker showed. Otherwise your code ends up producing lots of SettingWithCopyWarning and read-only copies. Also wastes memory.